# How to prevent window.location.pathname from escaping characters in URL

Tags: javascript, google-chrome

I am developing a google app engine app. I am trying to redirect user to login page when a button is clicked. To do this I set `window.location.pathname` to following string `/_ah/login?continue=http%3A//localhost%3A8080/`. However, chrome escapes the string so that the full URL becomes `http://localhost:8080/_ah/login%3Fcontinue=http%3A//localhost%3A8080/`, and this gives a 404 error. How can I prevent this from happening? The URL that works is `http://localhost:8080/_ah/login?continue=http%3A//localhost%3A8080/`

Comment: This doesn't have anything to do with App Engine.

Comment: Ran into the very same problem. Sadly, my only way out was to add a `replace('%3F','?')` at the end... I my case the suggested 'use location directly' is not applicable since I am manipulating href attribute of buttons that will fetch ajax content.

Answer (score 11):

Set `window.location.href` instead.

Comment: window.location.href is doing the same thing and is what I was using initially. I think it doesn't escape ? but it escapes &. Wherever I had an & it became &amp; and this broke my app.

Comment: Sounds like you have a different problem.  If the browser is going to escape something in the location, it will use the %XX style, not HTML Entities like &amp;.  My guess is that you need to mark the string as safe in your templating engine so you can prevent it from inserting HTML Entities.  To verify this is the issue, view source on the affected page and look at the place where this value is rendered.

Answer (score 0):

I think you're better off just using window.location.href. In both Chrome and Firefox `window.location.href="/?foofoo"` redirects to `<domain:port>/?foofoo`

Answer (score 0):

You can use the following code in javascript to decode URI components:

```
decodeURIComponent(window.location.pathname)
```