# zend framework: url with special characters not matching with defined route

Tags: zend-framework, routes, zend-framework2

I have defined a simple route which also accepts query parameters but sometimes some browser encode the query params and it stops working.

```
'searchResultPage' => array(
                        'type' => 'Zend\Mvc\Router\Http\Literal',
                        'options' => array(
                                'route'    => '/search',
                                'defaults' => array(
                                        'controller' => 'Application\Controller\Index',
                                        'action'     => 'searchResultPage',
                                ),
                        ),
                ),
```

When I type **mydomain.com/search?q=test** it is working but when i type **mydomain.com/search%3Fq=test** (some browser specially mobile browsers encode the query params) it redirects me to 404 error page.

Comment: Why are you url encoding the question mark? You may url encode the part after that but not the question mark itself

Comment: @andrew I am redirecting using window.location.pathname = '/search?q=' + encodeURIComponent(searchString); browser is automatically encoding the question mark.

Comment: The query string is not part of the path, so this is more of a problem with your redirect than your ZF route.

Comment: Your answer can be found here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/6500863/1697459